# How to submit a GCP AI Platform training job frominside a GCP Cloud Build pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a pretty standard `CI` pipeline using `Cloud Build` for my Machine Learning training model based on container:

- check python error use flake8
- check syntax and style issue using pylint, pydocstyle ...
- build a base container (CPU/GPU)
- build a specialized ML container for my model
- check the vulnerability of the packages installed
- run tests units

Now in Machine Learning it is impossible to validate a model without testing it with real data. Normally we add 2 extra checks:

- Fix all random seed and run on a test data to see if we find the exact same results
- Train the model on a batch and see if we can over fit and have the loss going to zero

This allow to catch issues inside the code of model. In my setup, I have my `Cloud Build` in a build `GCP` project and the data in another `GCP` project.

Q1: did somebody managed to use `AI Platform training` service in `Cloud Build` to train on data sitting in another `GCP` project ?

Q2: how to tell Cloud Build to wait until the `AI Platform training` job finished and check what is the status (successful/failed) ? It seems that the only option when looking at the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training) it to use `--stream-logs`but it seems non optimal (using such option, I saw some huge delay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit an AI platform training job, you can specify a [service account email to use](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training#--service-account).

Be sure that the service account has enough authorization in the other project to use data from there.

For you second question, you have 2 solutions

- Use `--stream-logs` as you mentioned. If you don't want the logs in your Cloud Build, you can redirect the stdout and/or the stderr to `/dev/null`

```
- name: name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - -c
    - |
         gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training <your params> --stream-logs >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Or you can create an infinite loop that check the status

```
- name: name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - -c
    - |
        JOB_NAME=<UNIQUE Job NAME>
        gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $${JOB_NAME} <your params> 
        # test the job status every 60 seconds
        while [ -z "$$(gcloud ai-platform jobs describe $${JOB_NAME} | grep SUCCEEDED)" ]; do sleep 60; done
```

*Here my test is simple, but you can customize the status tests as you want to match your requirement*

Don't forget to set the timeout as expected.